# Bayes Theorem Application to Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

This is in reference to an [already asked and solved question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103451/conditional-probability-question).

I have the same problem statement:

> Bowl 1 contains six red chips and four blue chips. Five of these 10
>   chips are selected at random and without replacement and put in Bowl
>   2, which was originally empty. One chip is then drawn at random from
>   Bowl 2. Given that this chip is blue, find the conditional probability
>   that two red chips and three blue chips are transferred from Bowl 1 to
>   Bowl 2. **Solve using Bayes Theorem**

Bayes Theorem clearly states that:

$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)\cdot P(A)}{P(B)}$$

My question that specializes my post and separates it from the linked post, is an explanation of how `P(A)` is found.

According to the proposed solution in the linked question, `P(B)` is equal to `3/5`, which makes sense as there are 3 blue chips and 5 total.

How does the following make sense?

$$\begin{align}
&P(A) = \frac {\binom 6 2 \cdot \binom 4 3}{\binom {10}  5}\\
\end{align}$$

And later, how does that translate to:
$$\begin{align}
P(A|B) = \left(\dfrac 3 5\right)\cdot \dfrac{ \binom 6 2 \binom 4 3}{\binom {10}  5\cdot \dfrac{4}{10}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Read it again.  $\mathsf P(B)$ is *not* $3/5$.  That is $\mathsf P(B\mid A)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event $A$ is that 2 from 6 red chips and 3 from 4 blue chips in the first bowl are transfered.

The event $B$ is that 1 from the blue chips transfered into the second bowl are then drawn from it.

The probabilities are thus:

- $\mathsf P(A)=\binom 62\binom 43/\binom{10}5$ is the probability for transferring 2 from 6 red chips and 3 from 4 blue chips, when selecting 5 from 10 chips in the first bowl.
- $\mathsf P(B\mid A)=3/5$ is the probability for selecting one from the blue chips transfered to the second bowl when given that 3 blue chips were among the 5 transfered to the second bowl.
- $\mathsf P(B) = 4/10$ is the probability for selecting, from the second bowl, one from the 4 blue chips that were (originally) in the first bowl (since each from the 10 chips had an  equal chance of being transferred and selected; 4 from these 10 chips are blue).

  Hence the probability for transferring 2 red chips (and 3 blue) when given that a blue chip was selected from the second bowl is:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\mid B)&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(B\mid A)\cdot\mathsf P(A)}{\mathsf P(B)}\\[2ex]&=\cfrac{\dfrac 35\cdot\left.\dbinom 62\dbinom 43\middle/\dbinom{10}5\right.}{\dfrac 4{10}}\\[2ex]&=\dfrac{5}{14}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks, @GrahamKemp. What probability rule or law allows you to find `P(A)`? I understand it logically when you write it out, but I am trying to tie this back into some lecture material.

Comment: @wundermahn It is just the count for outcomes in the event divided by the count for outcomes in the space (where all outcomes are equiprobable).

Comment: Thanks @GrahamKemp. Lastly, why in your second to last step is it (10 2) instead of (10 5). Apologies for the questions

Comment: Ah, that is a typo.  Thanks for pointing it ouy. Corrected